# Change the display of events in boot-strap's Full-calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have multiple types of ongoing events which i want to display differently. The default way Full-Calendar is displaying ongoing events is with a strip across all the included days. How can i display ongoing event with icons for example - rather then the stripe ?

Here is what i want to achieve. [image]

I added a custom class and tried to change the display - but once an event is ongoing - the strip keeps appearing....

```
 {
     id: 2,
    title: 'Repeating Event',
    start: new Date('2017-05-01'),
    end: new Date('2017-05-05'),
    color:'aqua',
    className : "presentation"
     },
```

Here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/Ld07gav3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the strip using:

```
.fc-event-skin {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: none;
  color: red;
}

.fc-event-inner::before {
  background-image: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/linecons-free-vector-icons-pack/32/calendar-512.png");
  background-size: 10px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
}
```

I'm not sure what icon you want to use.